# Function returning none- Trying to find highest number in a set without using x

Tags: python, function, return

Hey so I am just starting out on python. I am trying to find the largest number among 4 numbers using a function with return. For whatever reason the function keeps returning only value d and only if it the highest int. Other set of numbers I put in yeild none. I solved it originally using max, but I cant use max for the assignment. Please let me know what im doing wrong!! Thanks!

```
a=num1=int(input("Enter 1st number "))
b=num2=int(input("Enter 2nd number "))        
c=num3=int(input("Enter 3rd number "))
d=num4=int(input("Enter 4th number "))


def CompareNumbers(a, b , c, d):    
    if(b > a):
        largest=b
        return largest
    if(c > b):
        largest= c
        return largest
    if(d > c):
        largest= d    
        return largest

largest = a 

e= CompareNumbers(a, b, c, d)

print(e)
```

Comment: I also tried just one return largest at end but gave me same result.

Comment: Think about it. Suppose you are calling the function with `CompareNumbers(1, 2, 10, 10)`. What happens next is that `b > a` is `True`, you assign `largest` to `b` and then you return `largest`.

Comment: And the reason it still does not work if you remove the first two `return` statements is that there are still bugs. Step through the function on a piece of paper for some input that is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You may not have encountered [for-loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) yet, but you will. My suggestion is to try and use one here:

```
def compare_numbers(a, b, c, d):
    # To start out, we'll assume the
    # first number is the largest, but
    # we'll be double checking that.
    largest = a

    # We put the rest of the numbers in
    # a list that we'll iterate over in
    # the for-loop below
    my_list = [b, c, d]

    for number in my_list:
        # see explanation below...

    return largest
```

In the empty for-loop I've written above, you'll want to write a bit of code that checks if `largest` is actually larger than `number`. If it is, Great! You don't need to do anything. But if `number` is the larger of the two, you need to set `largest = number`. If you do this correctly, when the for-loop ends, `largest` will be the biggest of the four numbers you put in.

Comment: Thank you. However for this assignment we havent learned for and in yet.